# In Django, Accessing Attributes Across Models and Apps

Tags: django, django-models

I have a function in a file (services.py):

```
def balance(revenue, expenses):
    bottom_line = revenue - expenses
    return bottom_line
```

The Revenue Model inside the Revenue App:

```
class Revenue(model.Models):
    revenue = model.DecimalField()
```

The Expenses Model inside the Expenses APP where I'd like to do a calculation on save and populate the "bottom_line" field:

```
class Expenses(model.Models):
    expenses = model.DecimalField()
    bottom_line = model.DecimalField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bottom_line = balance(revenue, self.expenses)
        super(Expenses, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I access the revenue attribute during the save override on the model above? Do I need to do a queryset to get the bottom_line attribute from the Expenses model?

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. Revenue and Expenses are two separate models with no link between them. So when you're calculating the bottom_line for a particular instance of Expenses, which instance of Revenue do you want to use? How will you tell?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The Revenue Model will have only one instance as a company can only have one revenue number. Should I have a foreign key from expenses back to Revenue? The reasoning being that a single Revenue object can have many expense objects connected to it?

Comment: You mean one Revenue instance per company, surely? In which case yes you would definitely need a ForeignKey, then you can refer to `self.revenue.revenue` for example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Great! Thanks for the help. Last questions... Just to be clear, that ForeignKey goes on the Revenue Model as "expenses = model.ForeignKey(Expenses)"?

Comment: No, on the Expenses model as `revenue`.

Comment: Thanks!! You were super helpful.